Calculation of upper bound for Bermudan Call options
I'm having trouble calculating the upper bound for a Bermudan call option and plotting both the option price and the upper bound. The issue lies specifically in the calculation of the upper bound in the attached code. If anyone knows of an R package that can assist with this, I'm open to suggestions.
Thank you in advance
# Parameters
S0 <- 40  # Initial stock price
K <- 40   # Strike price
T <- 1.0  # Time to maturity (1 year)
r <- 0.05 # Risk-free interest rate
sigma <- 0.2  # Volatility
num_paths <- 25000  # Fixed number of paths
time_steps_set <- seq(1, 70, by = 1)  # Different numbers of time steps

set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility

# Initialize vectors to store primal and dual values
primal_values <- numeric(length(time_steps_set))
dual_values <- numeric(length(time_steps_set))

# Loop over different numbers of time steps
for (i in seq_along(time_steps_set)) {
  n <- time_steps_set[i]
  dt <- T / n  # Time step size
  
  # Simulate asset paths using geometric Brownian motion
  Z <- matrix(rnorm(num_paths * n), nrow = num_paths, ncol = n)
  S <- matrix(0, nrow = num_paths, ncol = n + 1)
  S[, 1] <- S0
  
  for (t in 1:n) {
    S[, t + 1] <- S[, t] * exp((r - 0.5 * sigma^2) * dt + sigma * sqrt(dt) * Z[, t])
  }
  
  # Calculate option payoff at maturity
  payoff <- pmax(S[, n + 1] - K, 0)
  
  # Initialize cashflows and exercise decisions
  cashflows <- payoff
  exercise_decisions <- matrix(0, nrow = num_paths, ncol = n)  # Record exercise decisions
  
  # Perform backward induction
  for (t in n:1) {
    # Identify paths where the option is in the money
    in_the_money <- which(S[, t] > K)
    if (length(in_the_money) > 0) {
      # Regression: Use in-the-money paths to estimate continuation value
      X <- S[in_the_money, t]  # Stock prices at time t
      Y <- cashflows[in_the_money] * exp(-r * dt)  # Discounted cashflows
      reg <- lm(Y ~ X)  # Linear regression
      
      # Predicted continuation value
      continuation_value <- predict(reg, newdata = data.frame(X = X))
      
      # Immediate exercise value
      immediate_exercise_value <- S[in_the_money, t] - K
      
      # Decide whether to exercise or continue
      exercise <- which(immediate_exercise_value > continuation_value)
      cashflows[in_the_money[exercise]] <- immediate_exercise_value[exercise]
      
      # Record exercise decisions
      exercise_decisions[in_the_money[exercise], t] <- 1
    }
  }
  
  # Discount cashflows back to the present value for primal value
  primal_values[i] <- mean(cashflows * exp(-r * dt))
  
  
  
  C_k <- matrix(0, nrow = num_paths, ncol = n)  # Continuation value for all paths and times
  M_k <- matrix(0, nrow = num_paths, ncol = n + 1)  # Martingale correction for all paths and times
  stopping_times <- rep(n, num_paths)  # Start with stopping at the last step
  
  dual_cashflows <- payoff
  for (t in (n - 1):1) {
    # Approximate the continuation value using regression
    X <- S[, t]  # Stock prices at time t
    Y <- dual_cashflows * exp(-r * dt)  # Discounted future cashflows
    
    # Exclude the first column of S for regression
    reg <- lm(Y ~ poly(X, degree = 2))  # Polynomial regression (degree 2)
    C_k[, t] <- predict(reg, newdata = data.frame(X = X))  # Continuation values
    
    # Compute martingale increment
    delta_M <- dual_cashflows - C_k[, t]
    M_k[, t] <- M_k[, t + 1] + delta_M
    
    # Update stopping times
    stopping_condition <- payoff - M_k[, t] >= C_k[, t]
    stopping_times <- ifelse(stopping_condition, t, stopping_times)
    
    # Update dual cashflows
    dual_cashflows <- ifelse(stopping_condition, payoff, C_k[, t])
  }
  
  # Calculate the dual price as the average of the maximum adjusted payoffs across all paths
  dual_prices <- sapply(1:num_paths, function(i) {
    max(payoff[i] - M_k[i, ])
  })
  dual_values[i] <- mean(dual_prices)
}


# Plot the results
plot(time_steps_set, primal_values, type = "l", col = "red", lwd = 2,
     xlab = "Number of Time Steps", ylab = "Option Price",
     main = "Option Price and Dual Option Price", ylim = c(4, 7))  # Set y-axis limits
lines(time_steps_set, dual_values, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
legend("topright", legend = c("Option Value", "Dual Value"),
       col = c("red", "blue"), lwd = 2)
grid()

